# jqGrid select with dataurl show ID and not VALUE

Tags: listview, jqgrid

In editform, the list works fine. But in listview shows the ID of dropdown. if add " formatter:'select'", shows in blank.

Jquery:

```
$(function(){ 
$("#list").jqGrid({
url:'grillas/ingresosEgresos.php',
datatype: 'xml',
mtype: 'GET',
...
{name:'id_entidad', index:'id_entidad', width:90,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, edittype:'select', editoptions: { dataUrl: 'select/select.php'}},
```

select.php:

```
echo '<select>';
$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysql_error()); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
     echo '<option value="'.$row[id].'">'.$row[entidad].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Thank you and excuse my english

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem and believe that this is a BUG. `dataUrl` seems doesn't cope well with `formatter : select` option.  Anyway, I abandoned `dataUrl`, and use `value` and have PHP to generate the option values.

```
$.extend(true,
{
    name:'part_id'
    ,index:'part_id'
    ,edittype:'select'
    ,formatter:'select'
    ,editoptions: { value: "<?=$parts_options_str?>" }
```

The string format is like `"$row[id]:$row[entidad];"` 
Hope that helps~